# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) error while using Wicked gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

I am getting this error while signing up user in the last step, user gets signed up but i don't know why is this error coming.

```
private
 def redirect_to_finish_wizard
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thanks for signing up."
 end
```

Please any solution

Comment: show the full error stack ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change your `redirect_to_finish_wizad` method as below :

```
private

  def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil)
    redirect_to root_path , notice: "Thank you for signing up."
  end
```

This will solve your issue. For more information about method look at [here](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/blob/master/lib/wicked/controller/concerns/render_redirect.rb).

Comment: `redirect_to_finish_wizard options = nil, params = {}` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

The gem seems to have been modified again and the `redirect_to_finish_wizard` method accepts 2 arguments instead of 1.

Try changing your `redirect_to_finish_wizard` method as below if the previous code breaks:

```
private

  def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil, params = nil)
    redirect_to root_path , notice: "Thank you for signing up."
  end
```